# PostgreSQL with serial fields , rule and wrong currval / sequence

Tags: postgresql, triggers, rules

Usually insert records into a log table based on CRUD events with PotsgreSQL requires (at least) one trigger and one trigger function. I tried to make it easier, using Postgres RULES. And it almost work, except for the scenario below:

```
create table mydata ( somedata char(4) , id1 bigserial );
create table mylog ( logid bigint , op char(1), id2 bigserial );
create rule mydata_ilog as on insert to mydata do insert into mylog( logid , op ) values ( new.id1 ,'i' );
insert into mydata( somedata ) values ('0001');
```

The main table and log table have a serial field, and I expect -- after insert one record into `mydata` -- to have one record in mydata with `id1=1`, and one record in `mylog`, with `logid=1` ( as the id of mydata record), and `id2=1`...  At `mydata`, `id1=1`, right ... ay `mylog`, `id2` is 1, right ... but at `mylog`, `logid` field is `2`, and the database sequence created to increment the `id1` serial field is `2` ...

```
select currval('mydata_id1_seq'); -- return 2 ?!
select last_value from mydata_id1_seq; -- return 2 ?!
select id1 from mydata -- return 1 ok 
select id2 from mydata -- return 1 ok 
select logid from mylog -- return 2 ?!
```

I already solved this with a trigger and a trigger function, works fine. But, is there any reason to PostgreSQL do this ?!

Comment: What you learned is don't use rules. My experience is they are non-deterministic. Instead of wasting time going down the rabbit hole to figure out what happened, use the trigger solution and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, COSTS OFF) INSERT INTO mydata (somedata) VALUES ('0001');
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on myschema.mydata
   ->  Result
         Output: '0001'::character(4), nextval('mydata_id1_seq'::regclass)
 
 Insert on myschema.mylog
   ->  Result
         Output: nextval('mydata_id1_seq'::regclass), 'i'::character(1), nextval('mylog_id2_seq'::regclass)
(7 rows)
```

A rule rewrites a query, using the same expression that gets used for `mydata.id` for the second statement, so you have the `nextval` call in both statements.

Rules for data modifying queries are difficult to get right, and you just stepped into a typical trap. Use triggers.